# Joining two states before submitting REACT form

Tags: reactjs

I always have this dilemma when i am submitting a form with values from two different useStates.
My first useState collects data from a form as follows:

```
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState({
    title: '10',
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    occupation: '',
    phone: '',
    dob: '',
  });

const onChange = (e) => {
    setCurrent({ ...current, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
```

Then i have another useState that takes value from a date picker (joining them in one useState was always a dream but ok...)

```
 const [dateob, handleDOB] = useState(new Date());
```

now when submitting the form i want to submit current using `editUser(current)` but before that i need to include `dateob` in the `current` object
if i put the `setCurrent` in the `onSubmit` function it wont work. What is the best solution for that?

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCurrent({...current, dob: dateob}) // this wont work as editUser will run before setCurrent is finished
    editUser(current);
  };
```

Comment: Setting the state in React is asynchronous, have you considered using [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)?

Comment: yes but then it will reset the inital values. 
I tried:
 useEffect(() => {
    setCurrent({...current, dob: dateob})

    
  }, [dateob]);

Do you have a proposed solution?
Thank you

Comment: It's a bad idea to ***set*** the state inside `useEffect`, you just ***use*** it instead. So the `useEffect` callback should just contain a call to your `editUser` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do it.

1. You can use `useReducer` instead of the `useState`, you can see the implementation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)
2. You could use `useEffect` hook. And when the `currentUser` changes - it should invoke `editUser`

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCurrent({...current, dob: dateob}) // this changes the reference to the current object
  };
```

and then

```
useEffect(() => {
 editUser(current) //this will only run when the reference to the current changes
}, [current])
```

you can read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) on the implementation

3. You can do it in the state update (I won't recommend). [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

```
setCurrent(existing => {
  const updated = {...current, ...existing, dob: dateob}
  
  editUser(updated)
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I will read more about solution 1 and 3. Regarding solution 2, my problem is that editUser will run every time current changes and that would be every time a user changes a field no?
const onChange = (e) => {
    setCurrent({ ...current, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

Comment: but i only want editUser to run when the user finishes editing/filling the form and wants to submit...

Comment: Then put it in the submit method. We're only working with what you give us :)

Comment: well to solve this i tried to create a setFinal state that will merge the 2 values (current and dateob)  before submitting but i am getting 2 different objects now inside final. is there a way to merge these 2 objects? 
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFinal({ current, dob: dateob }); 
  };